# How can I activate subpixel positioning with Pango and (py)Cairo?

Tags: python, cairo, pango, pycairo, pangocairo

I just came across [this article](https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2019/07/27/more-text-rendering-updates/) saying that subpixel positioning was added to Pango 1.44 in 2019 - not without its issues though. Apparently it is [switched off by default](https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2019/08/07/pango-1-44-wrap-up/). Both articles go as far as saying that the latest master from cairo is needed. Maybe it has been released in the meantime (?).

Two questions actually:

- Which version / release of Cairo (or pycairo for that matter) do I need for activating this feature? Or do I (still) need to build cairo from (unreleased) master?
- **How do I activate subpixel positioning with Cairo (pycairo) / pangocairo?**

---

There are multiple Python bindings to pangocairo. I am using the following approach in Python 3:

```py
import cairo

import gi
gi.require_version('Pango', '1.0')
gi.require_version('PangoCairo', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Pango, PangoCairo
```

My text rendering looks about as follows:

```py
_alignments = {
    'tl': lambda width, height: (0.0, 0.0), # top left
    'tc': lambda width, height: (-width / 2, 0.0), # top center
    'tr': lambda width, height: (-width, 0.0), # top right
    'cl': lambda width, height: (0.0, -height / 2), # center left
    'cc': lambda width, height: (-width / 2, -height / 2), # center center
    'cr': lambda width, height: (-width, -height / 2), # center right
    'bl': lambda width, height: (0.0, -height), # bottom left
    'bc': lambda width, height: (-width / 2, -height), # bottom center
    'br': lambda width, height: (-width, -height), # bottom right
}

def make_font(family, size):
    return Pango.font_description_from_string(f'{family:s} {size:.2f}')

font = make_font('Arial', 10.0)
x = 0.0
y = 0.0
angle = 0.0
font_color = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5)
text = 'test'

_ctx.save() # _ctx is a cairo.Context object

layout = PangoCairo.create_layout(_ctx)
layout.set_font_description(font)
layout.set_markup(text, -1)

_ctx.set_source_rgba(*font_color)

_, text_extents = layout.get_pixel_extents()
text_width, text_height = text_extents.width, text_extents.height

_ctx.translate(x, y)
if angle != 0.0:
    _ctx.rotate(angle)
_ctx.translate(*self._alignments[alignment](text_width, text_height))
_ctx.move_to(0.0, 0.0)

PangoCairo.show_layout(_ctx, layout)

_ctx.restore()
```

Comment: Related: https://lists.cairographics.org/archives/cairo/2020-May/028985.html

Answer (score 1):

> Which version / release of Cairo (or pycairo for that matter) do I need for activating this feature? Or do I (still) need to build cairo from (unreleased) master?

Random guess: This is related to `src/cairo-ft-font.c` in cairo, so I took a quick
look at the output of `git log src/cairo-ft-font.c`. The third entry
sounds like what you are looking for:

```
commit ea9329215d3431ded51a71b724baf0edc25ad633
Author: Matthias Clasen <mclasen@redhat.com>
Date:   Sat Jul 28 12:25:47 2018 +0000

    image compositor: Support subpixel positioning

    Support subpixel positioning with a 4x4 subpixel grid.

    When compositing glyphs in the image compositor,
    we store the subpixel phases in the high bits of the
    glyph index. The _cairo_scaled_glyph_index() macro
    has been updated to discard these bits. By storing
    the phases in the glyph index, the glyph cache just
    keeps working. When loading a glyph, the Freetype
    font backend shifts the outline according to the
    phases.
```

So, what is the first release that contains this commit?

```
$ git describe --contains ea9329215d3431ded51a71b724baf0edc25ad633
fatal: cannot describe 'ea9329215d3431ded51a71b724baf0edc25ad633'
```

Hm, doesn't seem to be in any release, so you need master.

> How do I activate subpixel positioning with Cairo (pycairo) / pangocairo?

You don't. As I understand it, it is automatically activated. The question then is: How do I deactivate it? And the answer to that also seems to be "you don't".

Edit: According to https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2019/08/07/pango-1-44-wrap-up/, the answer seems to be (partially) in the function `pango_context_set_round_glyph_positions`. This seems to handle the Pango and PangoCairo part of the support.

Comment: One of the blog posts explicitly says "To address this problem, subpixel positioning is now optional, and off by default". I have also tested this in much length against the latest *releases* of all involved libraries: There is no subpixel positioning for text in my described workflow ...

Comment: Are you referring to the blog post that says in the next sentence after your quote: "Use pango_context_set_round_glyph_positions (context, FALSE) to turn it on." If so, that seems like an answer to your question. (And, of course, one still needs a cairo version with this support, which is not the latest release)

Comment: Yep. I need to setup a test system and compile the stuff from scratch. Let's see how far I can get ...

Comment: From experience, the pycairo API looks a little different in a few places, so it is sometimes hard to figure out the equivalent strategy for pycairo.